# Forwarding command line arguments to a process in Python

Tags: python, process, arguments, quotes, command-line-arguments

I'm using a crude IDE (Microchip MPLAB) with C30 toolchain on Windows XP.
The C compiler has a very noisy output that I'm unable to control, and it's very hard to spot actual warnings and errors in output window.

I want to write a python script that would receive arguments for compiler, call the compiler with same arguments, filter results and output them to *stdout*. Then I can replace the compiler executable with my script in toolchain settings. The IDE calls my script and receives filtered compiler output.

My code for executing the compiler looks like this:

```
arguments = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
cmd = '%s %s' % (compiler_path, arguments)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is that quotes from arguments are consumed on script execution, so if IDE calls my script with following arguments:

> main.c -o"main.o"

the value of **arguments** is

> main.c -omain.o

The most obvious solution is to put whole argument list in quotes, but this would require modification in compiler calling code in IDE. I also tried using batch file, but it can only accept nine parameters (%1 to %9), and compiler is called with 15+ parameters.

Is there a way to forward exactly the same arguments to a process from script?

Comment: A batch file can accept more than 10 parameters, look up the use of SHIFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell is eating the quotes (the python script never even receives them) so I suppose it's not very easy to get them 'unaltered'.

Comment: If the shell is eating them when Python is called, this isn't a problem.  It should also be eating them when using the same args for the compiler alone.  So using sys.argv would give you the same result.

I do recommend passing the args as a list to Popen, rather than a single string.  With the former, you control exactly what each argument to the command is, without having to worry about escaping.  (What if any of your commands have spaces?)

Comment: Very true remark. Well, i'll leave this answer for completeness sake (and because of the informative comment).

Comment: I'm not certain this answer is even correct. The fact that the asker mentions writing a "batch script" may indicate that he is using Windows — in which case the shell does NOT eat quotation marks; they get passed verbatim for the executable's runtime to process. Which raises a different question: does Python provide any way to look "behind" the "sys.argv" that's artificially constructed by the Windows C runtime, and see the real, verbatim command line that was actually passed to the newly spawned process?

Answer (score 4):

Give the command arguments to Popen as a list:

```
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
cmd = [compiler_path] + arguments
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 3):

As ChristopheD said the shell removes the quotes.

But you don't need to create the string yourself when using Popen: it can handle that for you automatically. You can do this instead:

```
import sys, subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], executable=compiler_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The subprocess module hopefully will pass the arguments correctly for you.

Comment: "The 'executable' argument specifies the program to execute. It is very seldom needed: Usually, the program to execute is defined by the 'args' argument." http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html